# Trying to add a delete button to PHP website

Tags: php, mysql, button

I'm new to php and trying to add a delete button to remove an object (job) from a list,
I want the delete button to appear beside each of the individual objects (jobs) and once clicked this job gets deleted from the database table. Below is the code for both my edit_jobs.php (displays all the jobs by a particular user) and the delete_job.php (suppose to remove that particular job from the table) Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong,

My edit_jobs page displays all the jobs in the table that particular user has posted.

```
<?php
        include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
        $id = $userid;
        $username = $_GET['username'];


        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE user_id ='$id'")
                or die(mysql_error());

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<a href="job.php?id=' . $row['job_id'] . '"> ' . $row['job'] . '</a><br />';
            echo 'category: ' . $row['category'] . '<br />';
            echo 'description: ' . $row['description'] . '<br />';
            echo '<a href="member.php?id=' . $row['userid'] . '">Clients profile</a><br />';
            echo '<br />';?>
        <a href="delete_job.php?job_id=<?php echo $row['job']; ?>"
                       onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this book?');">
                       <img src="images/delete20.png" alt="Delete Book" />
                    </a>
        <?php } ?>
```

The delete_job page

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
if (!empty($_GET['job_id'])) {
    $jobId = $_GET['job_id'];

    require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';

    $sql = "DELETE FROM jobs WHERE job_id = ?";

    $params = array($jobId);

    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $status = $stmt->execute($params);


    if ($status == true) {
        header("Location: edit_jobs.php");
    }
    else {
        $error_info = $stmt->errorInfo();
        $error_message = "failed to delete job: {$error_info[2]} - error code {$error_info[0]}";
        require 'error.php';
    }
}

else {
    $error_message = "book id not specified";
    require 'edit_jobs.php';
}
}
else {
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of problems with this code. Number one - I agree with the above about the vulnerabilities. However this is an easy fix; simply validate the job ID as an integer and don't execute the SQL code if it fails validation.

Number two - I think the $param = array($jobId) is incorrect. You're not passing job variable to the SQL code at all... It's providing a null value to the execution statement. I cleaned up your code, can't guarantee this will work as I can't see your SQL statements, but this is a better approach and should work right...

```html
# Include this before anything else...
require_once 'connect_to_mysql.php';

# Ditch the server GET validation check, waste of load time, store job ID in a variable off the bat
$jobId = $_GET['job_id'];

# Validate if the job is is numeric and not empty
if ((!empty($jobId)) || (is_numeric($jobId))
{   
    # Ditch the $sql variable for speed/memory, just include it in the prepare statement
    # Note the limit statement - it's good practice to limit deletion queries to only one row
    # if you are only deleting one row so additional data doesn't accidentally get deleted
    $stmt = $link->prepare("DELETE FROM jobs WHERE job_id = ? LIMIT 1");
    
    # This code prepares job ID as a parameterized query and tells the database to parse it as an int
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $jobId);
    
    # Execute and validate
    $status = $stmt->execute($params);

    if ($status == true) 
        header("Location: edit_jobs.php");
    else 
    {
        $error_info = $stmt->errorInfo();
        $error_message = "failed to delete job: {$error_info[2]} - error code {$error_info[0]}";
        require 'error.php';
    }
}
else 
{
    $error_message = "Booking ID is not valid";
    require 'edit_jobs.php';
}

# Make sure to close your database connection when finished...
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
$jobId = $link->real_escape_string($jobId);
$sql = "DELETE FROM jobs WHERE job_id = $jobId";
```

Comment: How would I go about making that into a button for each item? sorry im very new to php?

Comment: Given that `$jobId` is extracted from the query string, ***SQL INJECTION ALERT!*** (Seriously, use prepared statements! The OP already was!)

Comment: I tried $sql = "DELETE FROM jobs WHERE job_id = $jobId"; but im getting this error Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/DesignAJobHy/delete_job.php on line 19

Comment: It depends on how you create the $link object in `connect_to_mysql.php` file.

Comment: SQL injection vulnerability not repaired; have a -1.

Comment: @michaelb958: Agreed, vulnerabilities are bad but that doesn't seem to be the main concern here in this question.